# Requiring previous dir in php throws 500 error

Tags: php, php-5.6

I have a PHP file in my local machine where I require some files in previous folders like this

```
"require_once("/../function_collection/pagination_functions.php")"
```

it works perfectly on my local machine using WAMPP, but when i put this exact same line on my codes on the live server it throws a 500 error. What could I be doing wrong? and I have uploaded all neccessary files and folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need quotes around the require line.

`require_once("/../function_collection/pagination_functions.php");`

2. You're trying to use an absolute and relative path - ie. /../ won't work. Either use:

if its one directory up:

`require('../function_collection/pagination_functions.php');`

or use the full path, i.e.

`require('/path/to/function_collection/pagination_functions.php');`

Hope that helps!